# Testing a JavaScript class instance for a mixin?

Tags: javascript, mixins

So I recently read up about native mixins in JavaScript

```
const MyMixin = Base => class extends Base {
    mixinFunc() {
        return 1;
    }
};

class MyClass extends MyMixin(class {}) {
    classFunc() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Is there a succinct way to test if a class contains a mixin or do I just need to test for the existence of methods that the mixin adds?

Comment: Since your "mixin class" is dynamically generated I think testing the existence of methods is the only way.

Comment: @michael ... in addition to Felix' suggestion I'd like to put this very opinionated comment ... *The most "native mixin in JavaScript" in my opinion is a function statement with `this` context that must be applied only via either `call` or `apply` to anything that is considered to be an object.*